# For the "get_roll" function, how would I split a user's input, for example, "1d3", meaning 1 roll for a 3 sided dice, as a random integer?

Tags: python

```
import random

def get_damage(attack, defense):
  if get_roll(attack) > get_roll(defense):
    return get_roll(attack) - get_roll(defense)
  else:
    return 0

def get_roll(rollstring):

def main_menu():
  x = int(input("How many rolls do you want to take?: "))
  z = 0
  list = []
  for roll in range(0,x):
    print("Input attack and defense roll", roll + 1, ": ", end="")
    y = input()
    list = list + y.split(",")
  for element in range(0, x):
    attack = list[z]
    defense = list[z+1]
    print ("Attack: ", attack, "Defense: ", defense, "Damage: ", get_damage(attack, defense))
    z = z + 2

main_menu()
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
How many rolls do you want to take? 3
Input attack and defense roll 1: 1d3,1d3
Input attack and defense roll 2: 1d6,1d3
Input attack and defense roll 3: 1d6,1d10
Attack:1d3, Defense:1d3 : Damage: 0
Attack:1d6, Defense:1d3 : Damage: 2
Attack:1d6, Defense:1d10 : Damage: 0
```

Comment: I know I need to use a minimum value and maximum value for the user's input, "1d3", where the minimum value would be 1 and the maximum would be 3. From there I would use random.randint(min, max)

Comment: I guess you can use string slicing? like this string[0] string[1] string[2]

Comment: But I don't know how the input and the output are matching so please clarify.

Comment: In the last 3 lines of the sample output, it iterates 
```
Attack:1d3, Defense:1d3 : Damage: 0
Attack:1d6, Defense:1d3 : Damage: 2
Attack:1d6, Defense:1d10 : Damage: 0
```
However, I am trying to get
```
Attack:3, Defense:3 : Damage: 0
Attack:5, Defense:3 : Damage: 2
Attack:6, Defense:6, : Damage: 0

Comment: The input is supposed to indicate how many times the users rolls for a x number sided die. For example, 1d3, 1 roll for a 3 sided die. Instead of of the code returning the input, 1d3, I wanted it to return a random integer within the range of 1d3

Comment: is there some kind of input like `2d3` or `8d5`? or it's only `1d3` or whatever starts with 1d?

Comment: yes, I input 1d3 and 1d3 but I want a number that returns in the range of minimum 1 to maximum 3

Comment: it is any input so it can be something along the lines of 500d40

Comment: I posted an answer. please see. and if it needs improvement, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `random.randint`
Like this:

```
import random

def get_damage(attack, defense):
  if attack > defense:
    return attack - defense
  else:
    return 0

def get_roll(rollstring):
    repeat = int(rollstring.split('d')[0])
    torandom = int(rollstring.split('d')[1])
    for i in range(repeat):
        result = random.randint(repeat, torandom)
    return result
def main_menu():
  x = int(input("How many rolls do you want to take?: "))
  z = 0
  list = []
  for roll in range(0,x):
    print("Input attack and defense roll", roll + 1, ": ", end="")
    y = input()
    list = list + y.split(",")
  for element in range(0, x):
    attack = list[z]
    defense = list[z+1]
    attack = get_roll(attack)
    defense = get_roll(defense)
    print ("Attack: ", attack, "Defense: ", defense, "Damage: ", get_damage(attack, defense))
    z = z + 2

main_menu()
```

And I fixed some of your code.

Comment: This definitely fixed my problem with converting the die roll, 1d3, to random integers! Thank you.

Comment: I noticed a new problem with the code...
```
How many rolls do you want to take?: 2
Input attack and defense roll 1 : 4d20,5d69
Input attack and defense roll 2 : 3d50,2d100
Attack:  2 Defense:  42 Damage:  0
Attack:  49 Defense:  36 Damage:  13
```
It calculated the attack wrong because if I inputted "4d20", 4 rolls for a 20 sided dye, the lowest possible number to get would be 4, but the code output returned "2"

Comment: @WardellNull Oh, right. fixed the problem, please see.

Comment: And if there is more, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
rollstring = '5d5'
num_rolls, sides = rollstring.split('d')
rolls = []
for roll in range(int(num_rolls)):
    rolls.append(random.choice(range(int(sides))))
print(rolls)
print(sum(rolls))
```